# How to limit a multiple selection of a <g:select>

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to limit a multiple selection to 1, because I want this format of list. I want to see all list always and don't want a dropdown list, and If I quit `multiple="multiple"` apears a dropdown list.

So, this is the code:

gsp:

```
<div class="field ${hasErrors(bean: cmd, field: 'subtypes', 'error')}">
    <label for="subtypes">
        <g:message code="requestSRO.requestSubtype.label"/>
    </label>
    <g:select name="subtypes" from="${requestSubtypes}" optionKey="code" multiple="multiple" optionValue="description" value="${cmd?.subtypes}" style="width: 100%;height: 100px" disabled="${!requestSubtypes ? true: false}"/>
</div>
```

I think `<g:select>` doesn't have a property to set the max limit of selections.

Comment: Why you are using multiple="multiple" if you want to select only 1 option, remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `multiple="multiple"` to change the way the select is displayed. Instead, set the `size` attribute to a number greater than 1.

```
<g:select size="2" name="subtypes" from="${requestSubtypes}" optionKey="code" optionValue="description" value="${cmd?.subtypes}" style="width: 100%;height: 100px" disabled="${!requestSubtypes ? true: false}"/>
```

If you want to display the entire list of subtypes, you could set `size="${requestSubtypes.size()}"`.

Comment: If I quit multiple="multiple" apears a dropdown list. and yes I want to display the entire list of subtypes, but size="${requestSubtypes.size()} doesn't show me nothing...

Comment: @JavierEscudero As a simple example, `<g:select name="bar" size="${(18..65).size()}" from="${18..65}"/>` displays the full range for me in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.